# convert to sandbox

Tags: web-part, visual-studio, sandbox-solution, solution-package, conversion

How I can deploy a custom webpart solution inheret  Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart as sandbox solution ?
as [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615454.aspx#BKMK_ThinAssembly), there is a restrication on using this class in sandbox solution, is there any workaround to achieve that?